# How do I remove the head of this turn tap?

Tags: bathroom, taps

I believe this is called a turn tap. I need to replace the washer due to it dripping, however I've not had much luck removing the head. My thought was that the blue plastic piece would pop off to reveal a screw, but I've not been able to prise it off, and there's not even enough clearance to get a screwdriver under it. How do I remove this type of tap head to replace the washer?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If there isn't a hex hole at the back of the lever, then that blue cap must be covering the fastener.

Comment: Is there any non-destructive method to remove it? I guess I'm just going to have to break the plastic if it won't pop out and then try to source another cap from somewhere.

Comment: use a small mirror to examine all sides of the handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

My first guess is that there is a set screw under that blue cover. If not look carefully under the handle as indicated or on the back of the handle.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine out with a strong kitchen knife screw was under the blue plastic

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take a moment to take the [tour], you'll get a good feel for how this place is a bit different than most general discussion forums. (You'll also get a _free badge!_ redeemable for absolutely nothing, but it'll make you smile and feel better!) You'll also see that one-liner answers are _generally_ discouraged. There's nothing inherently _wrong_ with your answer, but we do generally look for a bit more "meat" in an answer.